# How to uglify coffeescript in a sinatra app?

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, uglifyjs

Using coffeescript in sinatra. With the following code. it is able to return and compile coffeescript as js on the fly. Is there a good way to uglifying the result before coffee spits it out? Hope the question is clear

```
get "/coffee/*.js" do
    filename = params[:splat].first
    coffee "../public/coffee/#{filename}".to_sym
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess [sinatra-assetpack](https://github.com/rstacruz/sinatra-assetpack) will do the trick.